# Laravel 5.5: File download FileNotFoundException?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, download

I'm building a projectmanagement system, where users can upload file attachments to tasks. These attachments are stored in directory 'storage/app/public/projects//'. Uploading works like it should, in the right directory under the right ID.

However when I want to download said attachment, somehow the file can't be found. I've provided the code from my up- and download methods, as well as my 'local' driver configuration.

Driver configuration:

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url'    => env('APP_URL').'storage'
],
```

Upload method:

```
$sExt = $request->file('attachment')->getClientOriginalExtension();

$sHashedName = substr(
    sha1(str_replace(' ', '', pathinfo($request->file('attachment')->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME))
), 0, 14);

if ( ! Storage::disk('local')->exists($sHashedName . '.' . $sExt)) {
    $request->file('attachment')->storeAs(
        '/projects/'.$oTask->project->id, $sHashedName . '.' . $sExt, 'local'
    );
}

$oTask->attachments()->create([
    'name'      => $request->name,
    'location'  => $sHashedName . '.' . $sExt,
    'user_id'   => Auth::id()
]);
```

Current download method:

```
public function downloadAttachment(Project $project, Task $task, Attachment $attachment)
{
    var_dump(rtrim(env('APP_URL'), '/') . public_path('/projects/' . $project->id . '/' . $attachment->location));

    if (rtrim(env('APP_URL'), '/') . public_path('/projects/' . $project->id . '/' . $attachment->location)) {
        return response()->download(rtrim(env('APP_URL'), '/') . public_path('/projects/' . $project->id . '/' . $attachment->location));
    } else {
        return $this->redirectWithAlert(
            'error',
            'download',
            'attachment',
            $attachment->name,
            '/projects/'.$project->id.'/tasks/'.$task->id
        );
    }
}
```

This was my last attempt before posting this question. I have also tried `Storage::url('/projects/<project_id>/<filename>')` and a number of other things, but none work. I have linked a public storage directory according to the Laravel docs (with `php artisan storage:link`). I'm probably missing something logical here, but I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The public_path function refers to `./public/`, and not the storage disk 'public' that can be found in `./storage/app/public/`

One way of solving this would be to replace `public_path('/projects/'` with `storage_path('app/public/projects/'`